# Using the nth package with xstring

Tags: errors, xstring

In a book I'm writing, I use the `\IfStrEqCase` from the `xstring` package in a command to organize access to several pieces of information I need throughout the document, without having to define a separate command for each. One of the keys is the edition/version of the book. Obviously, as this is liable to change, it's convenient to have this data localized to a single place.

In the colophon of the book, I have a copyright notice which includes the name of the book and the aforementioned edition number. I'm a big fan of the `nth` package, and use it elsewhere in my document. However, when I try to combine it with my command, I get compilation errors. Here's an MWE which demonstrates the error:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{nth}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\Gkeys}[1]{%
    \IfStrEqCase{#1} {%
        {edition}{10}%
        {author}{John Doe}%
        {title}{Title of My Book}%
    }[\textbf{??key not found??}]%
}

\begin{document}

\textbf{\Gkeys{title}}, \textsc{\nth{\Gkeys{edition}} Edition}\\
\Gkeys{author} 2017

\end{document}
```

When I try to compile this document with `pdflatex` I get the following error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.16 ...}}, \textsc{\nth{\Gkeys{edition}} Edition}
                                                  \\
?
```

I'm not sure what's going here to make this not work. If I define a simple command, like say `\def\BookEditionNumber{10}`, this works fine, but obviously that loses the convenience of the `\Gkeys` command I had declared.

EDIT:

A comment pointed out that since I declared `\GKeys`with `\DeclareRobusCommand`, I rendered it unexpandable, and thus `\nth` can't do anything with it. My impetus for doing so was to allow it to work with commands like `\section`. However, out of curiosity, I changed the command to be declared with `\newcommand` instead. Interestingly, this also failed to work. When I tried to compile *that* document, I got the following error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \let 
l.16 ...}}, \textsc{\nth{\Gkeys{edition}} Edition}
                                                  \\
?
```

Comment: You declared `\GKeys` as robust command, this isn't expandable and `\nth` can do nothing here

Comment: I see. The reason I did that was to make it work with commands like ``\section``. Is there any way to get it both ways?

Comment: Well, `\IfStrEqCase` seems to be unexpandable as well, so even if `\Gkeys` is not robust the next cause of mischief is `\IfStrEqCase`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\IfStrEqCase` isn't expandable, so even if `\Gkeys` would be expandable itself, the inner command isn't.

I suggest to use the expandable `\str_case:nnF` command from the package `expl3` for the checking, the syntax is almost the same compared to `\IfStrEqCase`.

The only thing to consider is that spaces are gobbled in the `\ExplSyntaxOn...\ExplSyntaxOff` domain. It is possible to use `~` here which acts as normal space token then (and not as non-breakable space)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{nth}

\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\Gkeys}[1]{%
  \str_case:nnF {#1} {
    {edition}{10}%
    {author}{John~Doe}%
    {title}{Title~of~My~Book}%
  }{\textbf{??key~not~found??}}%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\textbf{\Gkeys{title}}

\nth{\Gkeys{edition}}

\textsc{\nth{\Gkeys{edition}} Edition}

\Gkeys{author} 2017

\section{\Gkeys{author} 2017}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does the tilde, in this instance, cause a regular space, or a non-breaking space to be inserted?

Comment: Hmm, is there a way to insert a space without it being non-breaking?

Comment: Backslash + space os is a normal space, as in \ .

Comment: @ChristianHupfer What do you mean? In an `\ExplSyntaxOn` context, `~` denotes a normal space token, not the usual tie.

Comment: @egreg: Yes, sure. I typed on my smart phone and was on the way to leave the appartment. Of course ~ is the non-breakable space in non-expl3 - context

Answer (score 3):

You can use a handier interface such as

```
\defineset{my}{
  author=John Doe,
  title=Title of my book,
  edition=10,
}
```

In the macros below, you can define as many sets as you want; I also show how to define an abbreviated form like `\Gkeys` as an alias for `\getkey{my}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{nth}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\defineset}{mm}
 {
  \prop_set_eq:NN \l__keith_set_temp_prop \g_keith_set_initial_prop
  \keys_set:nn { keith/set } { #2 }
  \prop_new:c {g_keith_set_#1_prop}
  \prop_gset_eq:cN {g_keith_set_#1_prop} \l__keith_set_temp_prop
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getkey}{mm}
 {
  \prop_item:cn {g_keith_set_#1_prop} { #2 }
 }
\keys_define:nn { keith/set }
 {
  author  .code:n = \prop_put:Nnn \l__keith_set_temp_prop { author } { #1 },
  title   .code:n = \prop_put:Nnn \l__keith_set_temp_prop { title } { #1 },
  edition .code:n = \prop_put:Nnn \l__keith_set_temp_prop { edition } { #1 },
 }
\prop_new:N \l__keith_set_temp_prop
\prop_new:N \g_keith_set_initial_prop
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_keith_set_initial_prop { author } { ??MISSING?? }
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_keith_set_initial_prop { title } { ??MISSING?? }
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_keith_set_initial_prop { edition } { ??MISSING?? }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\defineset{my}{
  author=John Doe,
  title=Title of my book,
  edition=10,
}
\defineset{another}{
  author=Jane Doe,
  title=Title of her book,
  edition=2,
}


\newcommand{\Gkeys}[1]{\getkey{my}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\textbf{\Gkeys{title}}

\nth{\Gkeys{edition}}

\textsc{\nth{\Gkeys{edition}} Edition}

\Gkeys{author} 2017

\section{\Gkeys{author} 2017}

\nth{\getkey{another}{edition}}

\end{document}
```

[image]